# WPF Designer keeps crashing when I put StackPanels in my ComboBoxItems

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, combobox

I've been using WPF for around 8 months and I'm very comfortable in it. Using some questions and discussions I found on here, I learnt how to make my ComboBoxes stand out even more. but here's the thing, to put images and those items inside of a ComboBox item, I would have to wrap them in a Panel (whether it be a StackPanel or a WrapPanel), but whenever I do that the designer either doesn't load them correctly at all or just crashes. Everything shows perfectly when the application is launches

Here's my code, nothing out of the ordinary. And I'm using [this style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates) which is stored in a resource dictionary. Is there a way to make the code better or is the designer simply not smart enough?

```
<!-- COmbo Box -->
            <ComboBox Margin="0 5 15 0" SelectedIndex="0">

                <!-- All Items -->
                <ComboBox.Items>

                    <!-- General -->
                    <ComboBoxItem Margin="5 0 0 0">

                        <!-- Content -->
                        <ComboBoxItem.Content>

                            <!-- Panel -->
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <!-- Image -->
                                <Image Source="/Icons/Support Ticket/feedstar.png" Height="10" />

                                <!-- Text -->
                                <TextBlock Margin="10 0 0 0">
                                    General Support Request
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ComboBoxItem.Content>
                    </ComboBoxItem>

                    <!-- Display -->
                    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="CmbBxDisplay" Margin="5 0 0 0">

                        <!-- Content -->
                        <ComboBoxItem.Content>

                            <!-- Panel -->
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <!-- Image -->
                                <Image Source="/Icons/Support Ticket/monitor.png" Height="10" />

                                <!-- Text -->
                                <TextBlock Margin="10 0 0 0">
                                    Monitor/ Display Issues
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ComboBoxItem.Content>
                    </ComboBoxItem>

                    <!-- Sound -->
                    <ComboBoxItem Margin="5 0 0 0">

                        <!-- Content -->
                        <ComboBoxItem.Content>

                            <!-- Panel -->
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <!-- Image -->
                                <Image Source="/Icons/Support Ticket/sound.png" Height="10" />

                                <!-- Text -->
                                <TextBlock Margin="10 0 0 0">
                                    Sound Issues
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ComboBoxItem.Content>
                    </ComboBoxItem>

                    <!-- My Accoount -->
                    <ComboBoxItem Margin="5 0 0 0">

                        <!-- Content -->
                        <ComboBoxItem.Content>

                            <!-- Panel -->
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <!-- Image -->
                                <Image Source="/Icons/Support Ticket/admin.png" Height="10" />

                                <!-- Text -->
                                <TextBlock Margin="10 0 0 0">
                                    My Account
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ComboBoxItem.Content>
                    </ComboBoxItem>

                    <!-- Membership Support -->
                    <ComboBoxItem Margin="5 0 0 0">

                        <!-- Content -->
                        <ComboBoxItem.Content>

                            <!-- Panel -->
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <!-- Image -->
                                <Image Source="/Icons/Support Ticket/memship.png" Height="15" />

                                <!-- Text -->
                                <TextBlock Margin="5 0 0 0">
                                    Membership Support
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ComboBoxItem.Content>
                    </ComboBoxItem>

                    <!-- Contact Support -->
                    <ComboBoxItem Margin="5 0 0 0">

                        <!-- Content -->
                        <ComboBoxItem.Content>

                            <!-- Panel -->
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <!-- Image -->
                                <Image Source="/Icons/Support Ticket/contacts.png" Height="15" />

                                <!-- Text -->
                                <TextBlock Margin="5 0 0 0">
                                    Contacts Support
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ComboBoxItem.Content>
                    </ComboBoxItem>

                    <!-- Divine Service -->
                    <ComboBoxItem Margin="5 0 0 0">

                        <!-- Content -->
                        <ComboBoxItem.Content>

                            <!-- Panel -->
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <!-- Image -->
                                <Image Source="/Icons/Support Ticket/bible.png" Height="15" />

                                <!-- Text -->
                                <TextBlock Margin="10 0 0 0">
                                    Divine Service
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ComboBoxItem.Content>
                    </ComboBoxItem> <!-- End divine service -->

                    <!-- Announcements -->
                    <ComboBoxItem Margin="5 0 0 0">

                        <!-- Content -->
                        <ComboBoxItem.Content>

                            <!-- Panel -->
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <!-- Image -->
                                <Image Source="/Icons/Support Ticket/announcement.png" Height="15" />

                                <!-- Text -->
                                <TextBlock Margin="5 0 0 0">
                                    Announcements Support
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ComboBoxItem.Content>
                    </ComboBoxItem>     <!-- ENd Announcements -->

                    <!-- Reports and Audits -->
                    <ComboBoxItem Margin="5 0 0 0">

                        <!-- Content -->
                        <ComboBoxItem.Content>

                            <!-- Panel -->
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <!-- Image -->
                                <Image Source="/Icons/Support Ticket/statistics.png" Height="15" />

                                <!-- Text -->
                                <TextBlock Margin="5 0 0 0">
                                    Audits and Report Generating Assistance
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ComboBoxItem.Content>
                    </ComboBoxItem>

                </ComboBox.Items>
            </ComboBox>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say the designer "crashes"?  Surely there is an exception message!  Don't make us beg for information.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway There were no exception messages, just the standard “There was a problem with the designer. Please click here to reload.” And when it does, the ComboBox does not show the items.

Comment: I have pasted your xaml into a test project and I do not get the error.  When you get the error, is there anything in the Errors list?

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using? (Put it in the tags) Also have you tried the editor in Blend? Also do you load a VM in the background?

Comment: That error still happens when you use the `ComboBox` with just one single item? And what about with a single item without any content (this could help you determine if the problem is coming from the style it is using)? And what about a `ComboBox` without any item?

Comment: If you're using the style you specified, take a look on the `StaticResource` bindings. Try to change them to `DynamicResource` and see if the error still occurs. If this problem happens only on design time, it might possibly be related with resource loading.

Answer (score 2):

`ComboBox` inherits indirectly from `ItemsComntrol`. To display your content efficiently on an `ItemsControl`, you should be setting a layout for your item's content on the `ItemTemplate` of the `ItemsControl`'s dereived class (in this case, the `ComboBox`).

[Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview) article on Microsoft describes how to use data templating to define a layout to display your content in WPF.

Defining a `DataTemplate` to display your content on the `ComboBox` would be as simple as this:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=MyImageSource}" Height="15"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="5 0 0 0" Text="{Binding Path=MyText}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Now, to use this correctly, you just need a class like this:

```
public class MyCoolData
{
    public ImageSource MyImageSource { get; set; }
    public string MyText { get; set; }
}
```

You can then have some collection with `MyCoolData` objects and set it as the value of your `ComboBox`'s `ItemsSource` property or, alternatively, you can manually add or remove `MyCoolData` objects directly on the `Items` property of your `ComboBox`. The Microsoft article above describes several examples of those. Or, to add your `MyCoolData` objects to the `ComboBox`, you can simply declare them in XAML, like the following example:

```
<ComboBox>
    <local:MyCoolData MyText="My first item" MyImageSource="MyFirstImage.png"/>
    <local:MyCoolData MyText="My second item" MyImageSource="MySecondImage.jpg"/>
    <local:MyCoolData MyText="Another one" MyImageSource="CoolImage.png"/>
</ComboBox>
```

---

Note that the examples I gave you above allow you to have your own object (in this case, a `MyCoolData` object) and use it directly as an item in the `ComboBox`. `ComboBox` data templating engine (provided by `ItemsControl`) takes care of creating the layout to properly display your `MyCoolData` object as a `ComboBoxItem`. The data templating engine uses the `DataTemplate` we defined on the example above to know how to display your object and it creates this layout elements as needed, for each of your `MyCoolData` objects. This ends up being more efficient, because you write less code and makes it simpler to change your code, and allows you to use virtualized pannels more efficiently, if that would be the case.

Comment: Although this answer doesn't answer directly why you're having that Designer problem, it might be a way to fix it or to help you find it, as simpler code allows you to identify the source of a problem easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using Visual Studio 2017, install and test it. If you are using VS2017, make sure you have the latest version by clicking the yellow flag and getting the update dialog.